# How to make existing columns empty in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, null

I want to make existing columns empty and in the future the column can not be filled.

```
application = models.CharField(default="noname", max_length=100, null=False)
```

Make existing columns empty and in the future the column can not be filled with any values.

Answer (score 0):

```
application = models.CharField(default="noname", max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
```

The editable attribute will make it disappear the form and django-admin and the field cannot be updated.